# Powershell GUI buttons arranged perpendicularly

Tags: azure, powershell, user-interface

I wrote a PS function to be run with ISE launch, so I can call it and switch the Azure subscription with a click of a button, but the buttons in GUI are listed horizontally, how can I change it to be shown perpendicularly?

Here's my code:

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Host
$sub = get-azsubscription | where-object -property State -eq 'Enabled'

function Set-Sub {
    $Title = "Powershell ISE"
    $Question = "Select default subscription"

    $0 = [ChoiceDescription]::new($sub.Name[0], $sub.Name[0])
    $1 = [ChoiceDescription]::new($sub.Name[1], $sub.Name[1])
    $2 = [ChoiceDescription]::new($sub.Name[2], $sub.Name[2])
    $3 = [ChoiceDescription]::new($sub.Name[3], $sub.Name[3])
    $4 = [ChoiceDescription]::new($sub.Name[4], $sub.Name[4])

    $options = [ChoiceDescription[]]($0, $1, $2, $3, $4)

    $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($Title, $Question, $options, 0)

    switch ($result) {
        0 { 
            Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor White ("Setting default subscription to "+$sub.Name[0])
            select-azsubscription -subscriptionname $sub.Name[0]
          }
        1 { 
            Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor White ("Setting default subscription to "+$sub.Name[1])
            select-azsubscription -subscriptionname $sub.Name[1]
          }
        2 { 
            Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor White ("Setting default subscription to "+$sub.Name[2])
            select-azsubscription -subscriptionname $sub.Name[2]
          }
        3 { 
            Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor White ("Setting default subscription to "+$sub.Name[3])
            select-azsubscription -subscriptionname $sub.Name[3]
          }
        4 { 
            Write-Host -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor White ("Setting default subscription to "+$sub.Name[4])
            select-azsubscription -subscriptionname $sub.Name[4]
          }
    }

}

$context = Get-AzContext
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White ("Currently used subscription is: "+$context.Name)
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White ("    ")
```

and that's how GUI looks like:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean vertically stacked? Or do you mean one or two buttons rotated 90 degrees relatively to the others?

Comment: While not a direct answer, you may want to look at https://poshgui.com/ for GUI related PS issues, a very useful tool.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible(I checked the official doc, seems no settings to change it to vertical). As a workaround, you can create a [list box control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/selecting-items-from-a-list-box?view=powershell-6#create-a-list-box-control-and-select-items-from-it) for vertically showing the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to make it vertical choices, it is not possible at this moment, though you can do differently for prompting every single option so that end user can select it: code would look like below:

```
$t = "Location"
$msg = "What location?"
$CFT = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&A choice 1", "1"
[Environment]::NewLine
$CON = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&B choice 2", "2"
$ELP = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&C choice 3", "3"
$CFT1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&A1 choice 1", "4"
$CON1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&B1 choice 2", "5"
$ELP1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&C1 choice 3", "6"
[int]$defaultchoice = 2
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($CFT, $CON, $ELP,$CFT1, $CON1, $ELP1)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($t, $msg, $options[0], 0)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($t, $msg, $options[1], 0)
```

Main problem with this approach as it will present one menu at a time with different prompt box.

But for nicer PromptForChoice for the PowerShell Console Host , you can use it like below:

## An alternative to the built-in PromptForChoice providing a consistent UI across different hosts

```
function Get-Choice {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        $Title,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [String[]]
        $Options,

        [Parameter(Position=2)]
        $DefaultChoice = -1
    )
    if ($DefaultChoice -ne -1 -and ($DefaultChoice -gt $Options.Count -or $DefaultChoice -lt 1)){
        Write-Warning "DefaultChoice needs to be a value between 1 and $($Options.Count) or -1 (for none)"
        exit
    }
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $script:result = ""
    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.FormBorderStyle = [Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
    $form.BackColor = [Drawing.Color]::White
    $form.TopMost = $True
    $form.Text = $Title
    $form.ControlBox = $False
    $form.StartPosition = [Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
    #calculate width required based on longest option text and form title
    $minFormWidth = 100
    $formHeight = 44
    $minButtonWidth = 70
    $buttonHeight = 23
    $buttonY = 12
    $spacing = 10
    $buttonWidth = [Windows.Forms.TextRenderer]::MeasureText((($Options | sort Length)[-1]),$form.Font).Width + 1
    $buttonWidth = [Math]::Max($minButtonWidth, $buttonWidth)
    $formWidth =  [Windows.Forms.TextRenderer]::MeasureText($Title,$form.Font).Width
    $spaceWidth = ($options.Count+1) * $spacing
    $formWidth = ($formWidth, $minFormWidth, ($buttonWidth * $Options.Count + $spaceWidth) | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
    $form.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($formWidth,$formHeight)
    $index = 0
    #create the buttons dynamically based on the options
    foreach ($option in $Options){
        Set-Variable "button$index" -Value (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button)
        $temp = Get-Variable "button$index" -ValueOnly
        $temp.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($buttonWidth,$buttonHeight)
        $temp.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
        $temp.Text = $option
        $buttonX = ($index + 1) * $spacing + $index * $buttonWidth
        $temp.Add_Click({ 
            $script:result = $this.Text; $form.Close() 
        })
        $temp.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($buttonX,$buttonY)
        $form.Controls.Add($temp)
        $index++
    }
    $shownString = '$this.Activate();'
    if ($DefaultChoice -ne -1){
        $shownString += '(Get-Variable "button$($DefaultChoice-1)" -ValueOnly).Focus()'
    }
    $shownSB = [ScriptBlock]::Create($shownString)
    $form.Add_Shown($shownSB)
    [void]$form.ShowDialog()
    $result
}
```

By this way, you have a better control of the form UI, you can put a blank textblock to make a new line and and in the loop you can create different button control.

Additional reference:

https://gist.github.com/DBremen/73d7999094e7ac342ad6#file-get-choice-ps1

Hope it helps.